# SQL: Pivot with placeholder rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table that stores one row for episodes of a show. Note that not every episode is stored.

```
showID    |    viewerID   |   episodeNumber    |    episodeDescription
____________________________________________________________________
15        |    ID-123     |      1             |    Scary
____________________________________________________________________
15        |    ID-123     |      3             |    Funny
```

I've built a pivot query to create columns for episode numbers and descriptions. Number of episodes is a known quantity.

```
showID    |    viewerID    |    episode1    |    episode2    |    episode3 
__________________________________________________________________________
15         |   ID-123      |    Scary       |     funny       |
```

My problem is that where there is no record for an episode, as shown in this example by the lack of row for episode number 2 in the first table, the query does not create a "place holder" and instead puts the data for episode3 into the episode2 column. I don't even know if what I need is possible -- but I do need to somehow make sure the episode number is associated with the correct description when there is no data (no row) for an episode number, and I do need to show a column for every episode in table 2 (so in table 2 above, the field for episode2 should be blank).

My query follows:

```
SELECT viewerID, showID, 
episodeDescription1, episodeDescription2, episodeDescription3
FROM
(
  SELECT viewerID, showID, col+cast(seq as varchar(10)) as col, value
  from 
  (
    SELECT viewerID, showID, episodeNumber, episodeDescription,
           row_number() over(partition by showID
                        order by episodeNumber) seq
    FROM tbl_showEpisodes
  ) d
  CROSS APPLY
  (
   SELECT 'episodeNumber', cast(episodeNumber as varchar(20)) 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'episodeDescription', episodeDescription
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  MAX(value)
  for col in (
    episodeNumber1, episodeDescription1, episodeNumber2, 
    episodeDescription2, episodeNumber3, episodeDescription3)
  ) piv;
```

I hope this is clear, and thanks in advance for any help! Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can PIVOT it on this way:

> ```
> create table tbl_showEpisodes (showID int, viewerID varchar(30), episodeNumber int, episodeDescription varchar(30));
> insert into tbl_showEpisodes values
> (15, 'ID-123', 1, 'Scary'),
> (15, 'ID-123', 3, 'Funny');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT showID, viewerID, [Episode 1], [Episode 2], [Episode 3]
> FROM (SELECT showID, 
>              viewerID, 
>              CONCAT('Episode ', episodeNumber) epNumber, 
>              episodeDescription 
>       FROM tbl_showEpisodes) src
> PIVOT (MAX(episodeDescription) 
>        FOR epNumber 
>        IN ([Episode 1],[Episode 2],[Episode 3])) pvt
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> showID | viewerID | Episode 1 | Episode 2 | Episode 3
> -----: | :------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
>     15 | ID-123   | Scary     | null      | Funny
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=404ae28ee1ef9936ec550d383f0f1d42)*